# List is displaying too wide and inline instead of Block in IE9

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble with a list displaying next to my search box in IE9 even though it is a block element.

```
<!--START MENU-->
<ul class="UtilityNav"><li class=" menuItem1 selected first"><a class="selected" href="http://www.ummsfoundation.org/page.aspx?pid=714">HOME</a></li><li class=" menuItem2"><a href="http://www.ummsfoundation.org/eventsNew">CALENDAR</a></li><li class=" menuItem3"><a href="http://www.ummsfoundation.org/giving">GIVE</a></li><li class="menuItem5 last"><a href="http://www.ummsfoundation.org/login">LOGIN</a></li></ul>
```

```
<!--Start QuickSearch-->
<table id="PC2781_tableMainAdd" class="QuickSearchFormTable" border="0">
<tbody><tr>
    <td>
        <label for="PC2781_txtQuickSearch" id="PC2781_lblTxtSearch" class="BBFieldCaption QuickSearchFieldCaption">Search:</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="PC2781$txtQuickSearch" type="text" maxlength="255" id="PC2781_txtQuickSearch" class="QuickSearchTextbox" onkeydown="javascript:if (isEnterPressed(event)) {try{document.getElementById('PC2781_btnQuickSearch').click();return false;} catch(e) {}} else return true;">
    </td>
    <td>
        <label for="PC2781_btnQuickSearch" id="PC2781_lblQuickSearch" style="display: none; visibility: hidden;">Search</label>
        <input type="submit" name="PC2781$btnQuickSearch" value="Search" id="PC2781_btnQuickSearch" class="BBFormSubmitButton QuickSearchButton">
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>


<!--End QuickSearch-->
```

This is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jelane20/NZF48/

I am trying to align Home with the left side of the search box, it works in Chrome and Firefox. I tried setting the width using initial and auto as suggested in another overflow question but still not working. Thank you for our help!

Comment: I first doubted Vector's comment and then I saw the fiddle and I agree with Vector now. At least format it.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the class ul.UtilityNav and change the display mode from block to inline-block. I've upload a new Fiddle with the css formatted but there are a lot of unnecesary classes.

```
ul.UtilityNav {
  width:auto;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Qv7am/3/